# Correct way of concatenating two columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame df with two columns "values" and "values1". I want to concatenate both these columns and create a new column "values2". Values are as follows:

```
values                  values1
[u'12f4',u'ff45']       [u'12f4']
                        [u'sd45',u'45ty']    
[u'12f34',u'ff2345']    []
```

If you noice the 2nd cell in column "values" is empty. And the last cell in columns "values1" is []. I want to concatenate as below -

```
values                   values1           values2                   
[u'12f4',u'ff45']        [u'12f4']         [u'12f4',u'ff45',u'12f4']
                         [u'sd45',u'45ty'] [u'sd45',u'45ty']   
[u'12f34',u'ff2345']     []                [u'12f34',u'ff2345']
```

Code I am using is -

```
df["values2"] = data["values"] + ', ' + data["values1"]
```

This creates extra commas or brackets. What would be an ideal code for this?

Comment: @jezrael Can you help me answer this question?

Comment: What is wrong with `df['values2'] = df['values'] + df['values1']`?

Comment: @JanTrienes That would give me [u'12f4',u'ff45'] [u'12f4']. Instead I want [u'12f4',u'ff45',u'12f4']

Answer (score 0):

Since you are concatenating text, I don't think it is possible to take advantage of numpy's ufuncs (I can be wrong).

So, assuming that, I would just use a list comprehension.

```
df["values2"] = [", ".join([str(data.loc[x, "values"]), str(data.loc[x, "values1"])]) for x in df.index]
```

Comment: That would give me [u'12f4',u'ff45'] [u'12f4'] for the first row. Instead I want [u'12f4',u'ff45',u'12f4']. Moreover, please look into the empty and [] cells and handle such cases.

Answer (score 0):

@[piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2336654/pirsquared) is right (as usual). If `values` and `values1` are lists, then...

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'values': [[u'12f4',u'ff45'], [], [u'12f34',u'ff2345']],
           'values1': [[u'12f4'], [u'sd45',u'45ty'], []]},
          columns=['values', 'values1'])
```

You can sum them like this...

```
>>> df[['values', 'values1']].sum(axis=1)
0    [12f4, ff45, 12f4]
1          [sd45, 45ty]
2       [12f34, ff2345]
```

Since the code you are using is `data["values"] + ', ' + data["values1"]`, and it's creating extra commas or brackets, it sounds like your data is not lists but are instead strings.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'values': ["[u'12f4',u'ff45']", "''", "[u'12f34',u'ff2345']"],
            'values1': ["[u'12f4']", "[u'sd45',u'45ty']", '[]']})
```

A million different ways to do this. If you don't need the 'u' in front of the strings, the easiest way to do this might be this:

```
import ast
df1[['values', 'values1']].applymap(ast.literal_eval).applymap(lambda x: x if x else []).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Can you kindly modify it so that it doesn't affect other columns in the data frame? There are multiple other columns which I haven't shown in my example. I am assuming your code will apply to the whole data frame.